# a question about vector in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I read some code written in c++ as following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int iarr[] = {30, 12, 55, 31, 98, 11, 41, 80, 66, 21};
    vector<int> ivector(iarr, iarr + 10);
}
```

in the above code, I pass `iarr` and `iarr+10` to `ivector(iarr, iarr + 10)` to create a new vector, is this a proper way to construct a `vector`? I checked the STL document, it is not mentioned there, is this allowed?

and also, array `iarr` contains 10 elements, should I use `ivector(iarr, iarr+9)`?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, can you make it more clear?

Comment: Did you compile and run the code to see what it did?

Comment: MGZero, I asked two questions, first, how can we pass a array as a paramater to a vector to create a vector object, second is should we change iarr+10 to iarr+9?

Comment: I believe the preferred way to do this is `ivector(&iarr[0], &iarr[0] + 10);`.

Comment: @crashmstr, I did, I got the output, just want to know how it works!

Comment: @aligray: Preferred for which reason? It's totally equivalent, only you get to type more characters.

Comment: Just in case the size of iarr changes. `vector<int> ivector(iarr, iarr + (sizeof(iarr)/sizeof(iarr[0])));`

Comment: @Jon Because letting an array decay to a pointer is `C` style code. I also think it looks semantically better. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed and yes, you are doing it right.

You are calling this templated constructor:

```
template<class InputIterator>
   vector(
      InputIterator _First,
      InputIterator _Last
   );
```

The template parameter `InputIterator` is `int*` (this is the type of the expressions `iarr` and `iarr + 10`).

Since the documentation states that `_Last` must point to one element *beyond the last* in the range, the `+ 10` is also correct to copy all 10 elements in the array (`iarr + 9` points to the last element, `iarr + 10` points to one beyond the last element).

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that pointers are Models of RandomAccessIterators and so are also Models of InputIterator.

Comment: @pmr: True, but IMO this information will not help the OP at all. Everything in its own time.

Comment: what is the InputIterator inside template<class InputIterator>? _First and _last is InputIterator, but we pass arrar1, the address of array, how this works?

Comment: @ratzip - That's what pmr meant in the comment above. A pointer is a valid iterator.

Comment: @ratzip: The constructor is *templated*. `InputIterator` is the name given to its template argument; we could have used any name, but "InputIterator" is good because it describes [the requirements](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/InputIterator/) this constructor has over the type used as `InputIterator`. The type used is `int[]`, which *decays* to `int*` as per C++ rules, and any kind of pointer satisfies the requirements for an input iterator (actually, as pmr says, any pointer satisfies the much greater requirements of a random access iterator).

Comment: Better do it this way instead of hard coding to value of 10.`vector<int> ivector(iarr, (sizeof(iarr)/sizeof(*iarr)));
`

Answer (score 5):

Simple helper for arrays:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t size(T(&)[N]) { return N; }

template <typename T, size_t N>
T* begin(T(&array)[N]) { return array; }

template <typename T, size_t N>
T* end(T(&array)[N]) { return array + N; }
```

Now you can write:

```
int main() {
  int const arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
  std::vector<int> vec(begin(arr), end(arr));
}
```

And not worry about the size of the array any longer, it'll be computed automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is a constructor of `std::vector`. It's this one:

```
template <class InputIterator>
     vector ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

It takes two iterators (in your case pointers), one to the beginning and another to the end of the sequence of elements that are to initialize the vector. The last parameter is optional, and you don't need it unless you're using custom allocators.

The iterator to the end should be one past the last element you want to include. So, if you want all elements from `iarr[0]` to `iarr[9]`, you need to pass in `iarr + 10`.

Answer (score 1):

It is allocating a vector using Iterators and the original iarr[] shown. There are ten elements and +10 is a proper iteration because it is one step past the end. That's how vectors work - it must point to one position past the end. It is copying the contents of the array into the vector. More clearly, it is using this template to create the vector:

```
template <class InputIterator> vector ( InputIterator first, 
InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

> Iteration constructor: Iterates
>   between first and last, setting a copy
>   of each of the sequence of elements as
>   the content of the container.

Answer (score 1):

This code is indeed allowed, if you check for example the documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

The range specified by the arguments follow the usual convention [first, last[, so passing iarr+10 is correct if you want the whole array to be copied

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is allowed, and `ivector` will contain 10 elements. And no, it should not be `9` because the end iterator should be *one step past the end*. If you know what ranges are, that range would be represented by this range: `[beginning, end)`. That is to say, include the first one, and go right up to but don't include the last one.

Because the STL (C++ standard library *cough*) is all templates, anything that supports the operators `++` and `*` (dereference operator) can be passed as iterators to the vector constructor. This property amazingly makes the same code work for both pointers and `vector` iterators. Standard library design at its best.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, last line in function main() calls constructor of std::vector. Have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/) 
to see all vector constructor overloads. The third one is used here. Its parameters are iterators for template type (template argument used here is `int` and so iterator is of type `int*`). Second argument is iterator that points to the first sequence element that will not be copied into vector.